# C++ array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I came across a C++ program like this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N = 10;
    int M = 2;
    int a[] = { 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9 };
    int(*b)[5] = (int(*)[5]) a;
    for (int i = 0; i<M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<N / M; j++) {
            cout << b[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The above program's output is `2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9`. It looks like `b` is an array point. So what does `(int(*)[5]) a` mean? Can someone help me to explain it?

Comment: Explicit convert `a` (`int[10]`) to `int(*)[5]`.

Comment: Can you give me more detail? What is the meaning of `(int(*)[5]) a`?  `a` is  an array(`int[10]`). And `int(*)[5]` means a point. Can they convert directly?

Comment: @Jonas double pointer? What double pointer?

Comment: @songyuanyao   Can you give me more detail? What is the meaning of `(int(*)[5]) a`? `a` is an array(`int[10]`). And `int(*)[5]` means a point. Can they convert directly?

Comment: convert it (1d array) to pointer to 2d array.

Comment: It means a should be casted to be a pointer to an array of ints that is 5 elements in size.

Just like if you do (int)(true) it will cast the bool to be an int.

Comment: I think it is UB BTW (strict aliasing rules, ...).

Comment: @lbs0912 You should, for good measure, accept an answer if it solves your question.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is an int-array with 10 elements: `int [10]`. `b` is a pointer to an int-array with 5 elements: `int (*) [5]`. `b` is initialized with the value of `a` and explicitly casted using the C-style cast: `(int(*)[5]) a`.

Effectively `a` is a 1x10 matrix and `b` is a 2x5 matrix, it is in fact a "reshape" of `a` into `b`, with the same content. The "most" dangerous thing here is that the reshape does not perform a deep copy, i.e., changes to `b` also affect `a` and vice versa;

The type, here `int`, is completely irrelevant. [Here](http://ideone.com/SjZM4o) is an online example, with several different types.

Answer (score 2):

Here, `a[]` is an array of 10 integers. `b` is a pointer to an array of 5 elements.

```
int(*b)[5] = (int(*)[5]) a;
```

In the above statement the address of the array `a[]` is type-casted to a pointer to an array of 5 elements. Then, `b` is accessed as a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
int a[] = { 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9 };
```

Looks like this in memory

```
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
a -> | 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 6 | 5 | 8 | 7 | 10| 9 |;
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      +0  +1 ...
```

When you access elements in the array you typically use [] but since `a` is an address. you can access
elements also using a pointer style offset

```
a + 2   // address to third int, *(a+2) the actual value `3`
```

Now by declaring another way to access the 10 integers you can access the memory of `a` in a different way, the type determines the way you access the memory

```
int(*b)[5] = (int(*)[5]) a; // compiler, pretend a is of same type
```

In the above statement `b` and `a` refer to the same memory but `b` is of type pointer to int array of five.

since `b` is a pointer:

`b` points to where `a` starts. doing `b++`, b now points to middle of `a` array since declaration of b says it holds only five integers

so

```
b[0] points to address a + 0
b[0][0] is the value of a + 0 or a[0] alt. *(a + 0)

b[1] points to address a + 5 
b[1][0] is the value of a + 5 or a[5] alt. *(a + 5)
```

Since C normally has no check whether you are going out of bounds the above works.

Answer (score 2):

Since `b`  is a pointer to array of 5 integers so :

- `b[0]` will point to an array of 5 integers stored from location pointed to by `b`.
- `b[1]` will point to an array of 5 integers stored from location pointed to by `b + (5*sizeof(int))`.

Since `b` has been assigned address of `a` via typecasting `int(*b)[5] = (int(*)[5]) a;`, therefore:

- `b[0]` will point to first 5 integers of array `a` i.e, `a[0..4]`
- `b[1]` will point to next 5 integers of array `a` i.e, `a[5..9]`

Now,

- `b[0][0]` will give **value of 1st element indexed at `0`** of array pointed to by `b[0]` i.e, **`a[0]`**
- `b[0][1]` will give **value of 2nd element indexed at `1`** of array pointed to by `b[0]` i.e, **`a[1]`**

**..**

**..**

- `b[1][0]` will give **value of 1st element indexed at `0`** of array pointed to by `b[1]` i.e, **`a[5]`**
- `b[1][1]` will give **value of 2nd element indexed at `1`** of array pointed to by `b[1]` i.e, **`a[6]`**

Answer (score 0):

Int-array a is explicitly initialized to contain 10 elements. The internal representation of the variable a is a pointer to the first element. Writing a[3] is "give me the contents of a with an offset of 3".

The variable b is then created as an array of pointers (length 5) to int (it is not "point" but "pointer", btw). b is initialized with the contents of a, but since a is of a different type, it has to be typecast to the correct type (that is, b's type). Type cast basically means "pretend that the memory of variable a was of a different type". This is here done with a c-style cast

```
(int(*)[5]) a
```

All in all, I wouldn't strive to replicate this coding style.

Also, the following code only works if a pointer to int is twice the size of an int, e.g. 64 bit pointer, 32 bit int. Dirty, dirty code.

Comment: "The internal representation of the variable a is a pointer to the first element." - No, it isn't. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: Ok, more precise would be to say "c-style arrays are not pointers, but you can use them as such".